# How to rename result assembly to have in installed in .m2

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have multimudule project. One of module is assembly, having descriptor to put  core (library) and examples in one zip.

```
<assembly>
<id>assembly</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
    <format>dir</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

This is my assemly, and this is plugin configuration

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I have resulting zip installed in my .m2 folder fine but the name is assembly-ccp-.... I need to rename it to my-project, it could be done with 2 lines in plugin:

```
<finalName>my-project</finalName>
<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
```

It is good in target folder (i can see my-project.zip), but now resulting zip is not installed in my .m2 folder. So, the question is how to make it installed in my .m2 folder?
(running from parent project with: clean install)

Found output:

```
[INFO] Building Assebly
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting directory /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/target
[INFO] [site:attach-descriptor {execution: default-attach-descriptor}]
[INFO] Preparing source:jar
[WARNING] Removing: jar from forked lifecycle, to prevent recursive invocation.
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [source:jar {execution: default}]
[INFO] [assembly:single {execution: package-assembly}]
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: assembly.xml
[INFO] Processing DependencySet (output=/)
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: com.comcast.xcal.mbus:assembly:pom:CCP-LATEST-SNAPSHOT; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[INFO] Building zip: /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/target/my-project.zip
[WARNING] Configuration options: 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false, and 'classifier' is missing.
Instead of attaching the assembly file: /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/target/my-project.zip, it will become the file for main project artifact.
NOTE: If multiple descriptors or descriptor-formats are provided for this project, the value of this file will be non-deterministic!
[INFO] Processing DependencySet (output=/)
[INFO] Copying files to /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/target/my-project.dir
[WARNING] Assembly file: /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/target/my-project.dir is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.
[INFO] [install:install {execution: default-install}]
[INFO] Installing /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/pom.xml to /home/dmitry/.m2/repository/com/mbus/assembly/CCP-LATEST-SNAPSHOT/assembly-CCP-LATEST-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] [javadoc:jar {execution: default}]
[INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
[INFO] 
[INFO]
```

Comment: You might want to check it out once again. This is controlled with `<attach>` setting of assembly plugin, and by default, it is `true`. So the zip archive should be in your repository.

Comment: setting <attach>true</attach> didn't helped, I can see zip in target, but it is not in repo.

Comment: Show log file of your maven execution.

Comment: [INFO] Building zip: /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/target/my-project.zip    [WARNING] Configuration options: 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false, and 'classifier' is missing. Instead of attaching the assembly file: /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/target/my-project.zip, it will become the file for main project artifact. NOTE: If multiple descriptors or descriptor-formats are provided for this project, the value of this file will be non-deterministic!     [INFO] Processing DependencySet (output=/)

Comment: You don't encourage people to help you by posting such comments.

Comment: sorry, don't know how to format comments. Take a look at first post

Comment: The output is not complete. What happens when `install` phase is being called ?

Comment: Why do you have `<format>dir</format>` ? I guess this line is causing troubles.

Comment: Don't remember why did I put this, think it is not nessesary for me, now I removed it, but still have the same output, without     [WARNING] Assembly file: /home/dmitry/mbus/trunk/assembly/target/my-project.dir is not a regular file (it may be a directory). It cannot be attached to the project build for installation or deployment.

Answer (score 2):

The name published in the .m2 repository is always `${module.artifactId}-${module.version}.${module.extension}` even the `finalName` is set and the package properly renamed in the `target` folder.

I found two ways to change that:

1. Not really a solution: change the artifactId (but it is the solution I finally choose for my project)
2. Set an `id` in the assembly XML:

   in assembly/resources.xml 
   -> `<id>` = desired postfix (e.g `<id>myappid</id>`)

   in pom.xml maven-assembly-plugin build section, set `appendAssemblyId` to true

   The result will be:

   - file name in target folder = `${artifactId}-${version}-${assemblyId}.zip`
   - file in .m2 repo folder = same as in target